# Group and Combine Rows In SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that I unfortunately can't alter, but I can use to create a view.  The issue is that the data in one column is spread across multiple rows.  Here's a sample of what that looks like:

| Customer | Activity | Note | Sequence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Note | The custo | 1 |
| 1 | Note | mer calle | 2 |
| 1 | Note | d and lef | 3 |
| 1 | Note | t a messa | 4 |
| 1 | Note | ge. | 5 |
| 1 | Charge | $39.95 | 6 |
| 2 | Charge | $14.47 | 7 |

I need the data to look like this:

| Customer | Activity | Note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Note | The customer called and left a message. |
| 1 | Charge | $39.95 |
| 2 | Charge | $14.47 |

Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: [String aggregation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: The answer will depend on what version of SQL Server you need to support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select   customer
        ,Activity
        ,string_agg(note, '') within group (order by Sequence) as note
from     t
group by customer, Activity
```

| customer | Activity | note |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Charge | $39.95 |
| 2 | Charge | $14.47 |
| 1 | Note | The customer called and left a message |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LWVXN71M)

Answer (score -1):

try this:
STRING_AGG
Search for the syntax dialect according to the software you are using.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).